# SQL Two aggregate functions over three tables

Tags: sql

I'm doing a database project and I've spent about 3 hours confusing myself so I thought I'd try to get some help on here.

I have tables for music genres, competitions and entries to the competitions.
I need to work out how many competitions there are for each genre and how many entries there are for each genre.
My aggregate functions for competitions and entries work when I only have one in the query but when I have them both in the same query I get the results for the entries column in competitions as well and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, it's probably something stupid and simple.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT Genre.Genre, count(Competition.Genre_ID)Competitions, count(Comp_Entry.Comp_ID)Bands
FROM Genre, Competition, Comp_Entry
WHERE Genre.Genre_ID = Competition.Genre_ID
AND Comp_Entry.Comp_ID = Competition.Comp_ID
GROUP BY Competition.Genre_ID, Genre.Genre
ORDER BY Genre.Genre;
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper `join` syntax.  But the problem you are facing is that you need `count(distinct)` rather than `count()`:

```
SELECT Genre.Genre, count(Competition.Genre_ID) as Competitions,
       count(distinct Comp_Entry.Comp_ID) as Bands
FROM Genre join
     Competition
     on Genre.Genre_ID = Competition.Genre_ID join
     Comp_Entry
     on Comp_Entry.Comp_ID = Competition.Comp_ID
GROUP BY Competition.Genre_ID, Genre.Genre
ORDER BY Genre.Genre;
```

Comment: Thanks but that's changed the data in the competition column all to 1 now and has made the data in the bands column wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: "count(distinct Comp_Entry.Comp_ID) as Bands" is correct without the distinct in it but when you add it, it's wrong.

Comment: If you are only getting one row, then you might be leaving out the `group by` clause.

Comment: 'now', not 'row'. Every field in that column has been set to 1.